# Launch CSS animation on Load and hover/out

Tags: css

I want to launch an animation in two cases:

- Right at the beginning when page loads
- Whenever a users hover/out the svg

I know how to do the hover/out with CSS transitions, but:
How do I launch the animation you see also on load?

The same animation you see when you hover/out I want to launch it at the beginning, when the page loads.

Not sure how to implement it

Thanks a lot

https://codepen.io/fernandocomet/pen/poaqZEN?editors=1100

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.animation-design {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 215px;
  height: 215px;
  border: solid 1.2px #4d4e53;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.animation-design .left,
.animation-design .right {
  transition: all 3s;
  transition-timing: ease-in-out;
}




.animation-design:hover .left {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.animation-design:hover .right {
  transform: translateX(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}

/******** Responsive Media Query ***********/
@media (max-width: 568px) { 
  
    .animation-design {
      width: 132px;
      height: 132px;
    }
    .left, .right {
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
    }
    .right {
      position: absolute;
      left: 38px;
      top: 38px;
    }

    .animation-design:hover .left {
      transform: translateX(38px) rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .animation-design:hover .right {
      transform: translateX(-38px) rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="animation-design">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is to add an animation to an element on body load through javascript like so

```js
let p = document.getElementById('PageLoad')
window.document.body.onload = function() {
p.style.animation = 'color 4s'
}
```

```css
@keyframes color {
  0%   {background-color: red;}
  25%  {background-color: yellow;}
  50%  {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}
```

```html
<p id='PageLoad'> hello world </p>
```